# Responsive Header Image CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I set an image as header which is responsive?
I've tried already the Bootstrap's img-responsive class, but the height is to large on small screens.

I've tried this, but the image has each time the original size:

```
@media (max-height: 700px){
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width:auto;
        max-width:100%;
        height:250px;
    }
}

/* sm */
@media (min-height: 701) {
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width:auto;
        max-width:100%;
        height:275px;
    }
}
/* md */
@media (min-height: 999px) {
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width:auto;
        max-width:100%;
        height:400px;
    }
}
/* lg */
@media (min-height: 1200px) {
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        max-width:100%;
        height:500px;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using bootstrap + setting `max-height: Xpx` to your image?

Comment: try with this shorcut -  <img src= "" width="100%"/>

Comment: What does your min-height refer to? Screen height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.img-theme{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-heigth: 500px !important;
}
```

This should auto-resize height based on width, 100% make the image responsive of device screen width. And your image won't be taller than 500 pixels.

Here is an example:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

.img-theme{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 500px !important;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-theme" src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-5.jpg">
```

You don't need to use media-queries... just place it in your global css file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Use Width:auto width always 100%; in any resolution now its working fine check it once

```css
@media (max-height: 700px){
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:250px;
    }
}

/* sm */
@media (min-height: 701) {
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:275px;
    }
}
/* md */
@media (min-height: 999px) {
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        height:400px;
    }
}
/* lg */
@media (min-height: 1200px) {
    .img-theme {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height:500px;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/nature-wallpapers-5.jpg" class="img-theme"/>
```